# Can't connect to a network from the Windows 8 Modern UI (have to switch to desktop mode)?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8, modern-ui

I can't figure out how to switch networks on Windows 8 in the Modern UI (I can do it from the desktop mode though).

I move my mouse to the right side to bring up the side menu. This also brings up the network/battery/clock box to the left... no matter how fast I move my mouse to that box it disappears before I an reach it.

I thought maybe there was an option under PC Settings>Wireless but that only lets me turn on/off Airplane Mode and the WiFi signal overall.

How do you reach that box that pops up on the left with the network/battery/clock before it disappears?

Comment: It's in the settings charm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swipe in from the right of the screen to get the charms and click on settings and here it is:

This is brings up the same screen as the network icon in the tray area.

[image: The location of the network icon]

Comment: Hidden in plain sight... argh!

Comment: Yes, it's very non-obvious. It's even worse the first time I was looking for the shutdown option. I ended up running `shutdown` from command line a few times.